# Executing Mass MySQL database restore from batch file using PowerShell

Tags: mysql, windows, powershell, batch-file

So what I have is about 80-90 MySQL DBs to restore and using < gives the 'saved for future use' error when used directly through PowerShell. The next step I tried was using just straight & cmd /c which also prompted the same error. 
I tried the code below, but I get either Access Denied or 'system can't find the file specified' and I'm trying to figure out where it's messing up. Any help is definitely appreciated.

**PowerShell**

```
$list= gci "C:\Scripts\Migration\mysql\" -name
$mysqlbinpath="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql"
$mysqluser="admin"
$mysqlpass=getpass-mysql
pushd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
foreach($file in $list){
$dbname=$file.Substring(0, $file.LastIndexOf('.'))
$location='C:\Scripts\Migration\mysql\'+$file
& $bt $mysqluser, $mysqlpass, $dbname, $location
write-host "$file restored"
}
```

The batch file called by $bt

**Batch**

```
"cmd /c "mysql" -u %1 -p%2 --binary-mode=1 %3 < %4"
```

getpass-mysql is a function I have that pulls the MySQL root pass (our root user is 'admin') as a string.

I hope this isn't a duplicate as I checked other posts first and tried those solutions (perhaps incorrectly applied) and they didn't seem to help.

I have updated the code block with the changes I have made. I am currently receiving the error about using the right syntax near ' ■-'.

Comment: You could escape the `<` in powershell using a backtick ` to avoid getting the error you got when running it in PowerShell directly.

Comment: That helped so much! Now I'm getting 'The system cannot find the file specified' I'm going to make sure the pathing is correct, but do you see anything in my formatting that would be causing it to read incorrectly?

Comment: Please edit your original question to add your updated code, and I'll see if I can spot any issues.

Comment: I went ahead and updated it.